# What beer is ok to drink not-cold or room temperature (for camping)

Tags: temperature, varieties

As in title, I'm going camping with some buddies soon and we're planning on bringing far more beer than we have space for in a cooler. What kinds of beer are palatable to drink (or good even) when at room temperature or even slightly warm?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/q/83/43

Comment: IPA. This beer was produced by the English to transport across the seas without spoiling

Comment: You don't need to drink a beer at room temperature. Find a stream, lake, pond or whatever and stick your beer in there for a while. If that's not available, dig a hole in the ground until the ground cools off. Stick the beer in there for a while with good contact with the soil. Cans work better for this. If you have an couple of hours, the beer might be at least cooled off into the 50s or 60s.

Answer (score 8):

Somewhat related: [What temperature should I serve my beer?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/q/5/73) In short, beers don't need to be served as cold as many are led to believe, and darker beers tend to be meant to serve warmer (as warm as 55°F). You certainly don't want to drink warm Coors, so maybe bring along some stouts.

In case there isn't a stream around to do what @user23614 suggests, bring some newspapers. Wet a sheet of newspaper and wrap the bottle with a single layer. Leave the bottle somewhere the breeze can blow on it, until most of the water evaporates. This is probably a common camping trick, but I first saw Moroccans in the Sahara Desert do this to chill a bottle of wine.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: no beer that has color-changing mountains on the side should be served warm, otherwise you'll taste it.

Long answer:

First, ales are traditional served warmer than pilseners, so start your selection there.

Second consideration is sweet/bitter balance. Sweetness generally becomes [stronger](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v438/n7070/abs/nature04248.html) with warmer beer. Something with a bit of sour would probably hold up well when warm. At the same time, styles that are meant to be sweet are usually served at/close to room temp: barleywines, or anything imperial/double/doppel/strong. Bonus: you won't have to carry as much.

Third: can you get it in a can? Cleaning up that campsite will be so much easier the next morning...

Answer (score 3):

My first temptation is to say none.  However there are two mitigation strategies to this dilemma.

The first is mulled beer, you need a light IPA, a saucepan, cinnamon and star anise.  Put the beer in the pan, add the spices and heat.

The second strategy, and one I've used, is camp near a stream.  Store the beer in the stream in a net bag or similar.  Any beer works in this situation and it will cool the beer to a drinking temperature.

Answer (score 2):

At room temperature the flavour of the beer starts to intensify, some people would say it gets more bitter.
I tried something that worked: there are beers like Kingfisher Light that have pretty good carbonation content.
So even at room temperature you get a good time. You can try any other beer that has strong carbonation and **little** mild in flavour.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine used to be barman in an old pub in Dublin. He said the old boys would get him to microwave the cold Guinness up to room temperature. Additionally,  non draught Guinness such as the old export strength stuff wadcdrunk at room temperature

Answer (score 0):

I like all light beers at room temperature. Always have. I ask my local bar tender to pull a bucket 1/2 hour before I come in and keep it out. (I call ahead and tip well) but always drink the bucket. If not, give the beers away so he doesn't re chill them and ruin them. Is this strange?

Comment: At a lot of restaurants and bars I need to ask them for unchilled glasses because they go hog-wild with the "cold beer" thing trying to serve like 2 degrees above freezing.  Sure, fine...but you can't taste the beer when it's that cold.
Really though, your drinking habits are between you and your bartender so if he's cool with accommodating you that's all the validation needed.  Most people serve light lagers that cold because the flavor's not considered that impressive, but if it's your jam then rock it.

Answer (score 0):

Beer is best to be drank at the temperature of 10C, but there are no real testing done on beer at room temp. You must do it yourself. It is pretty hard job to do   LOL.

Comment: Hi Aleksander, and welcome to Alcohol StackExchange!  Since your answer directly contradicts several other answers, can you expand on why you believe 10C is an optimal serving temperature for all beer?